# Setear valores obtenidos de azure key vault en spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

Trabajo con Spring Boot 2.7.11, Java 11, SQL Server 2022, JPA Hibernate

El tema principal es que estoy obteniendo los datos de azure key vault pero no se como setearlo al archvo `bootstrap.properties` el tema es que spring boot carga el archivo antes mencionado antes que pueda leer los valores de los secretos.

Para eso implemente la clase `MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner` que en teoria se ejecuta antes que cargue el archivo `bootstrap.properties` para poder leer los valores del vault y setearlos al archivo `bootstrap....`muestro el código que tengo implementeado.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>siac-market</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>consumir-api</name>
    <description>Demo consumir API</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure.version>4.7.0</spring-cloud-azure.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

KeyVaulSecretManager

```
@Component
public class KeyVaultSecretManager {


public String getSecretValue(String secretName) {
    SecretClient client = new SecretClientBuilder()
            .vaultUrl("https://pericotrespalotes.vault.azure.net/")
            .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
            .buildClient();

    KeyVaultSecret secret = client.getSecret(secretName);
    return secret.getValue();
}
}
```

MyCommandLineRunner

```
@Component
public class MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private KeyVaultSecretManager secretManager;

@Value("${spring-datasource-url}")
private String urlSecret;

@Value("${spring-datasource-username}")
private String usernameSecret;

@Value("${spring-datasource-password}")
private String passwordSecret;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    // Recuperar secretos de Azure Key Vault
    String urlSecret = secretManager.getSecretValue("spring-datasource-url");
    String usernameSecret = secretManager.getSecretValue("spring-datasource-username");
    String passwordSecret = secretManager.getSecretValue("spring-datasource-password");

    // Carga las propiedades desde el archivo application.properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/bootstrap.properties");
    properties.load(inputStream);

    // Actualiza las propiedades existentes con los valores recuperados de Azure Key Vault
    properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", urlSecret);
    properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", usernameSecret);
    properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", passwordSecret);

    // Usa un objeto FileOutputStream para escribir las propiedades actualizadas en el archivo application.properties
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/bootstrap.properties");
    properties.store(outputStream, "Azure Key Vault secrets");

    // Actualiza las variables de instancia con los valores recuperados de Key Vault
    this.urlSecret = urlSecret;
    this.usernameSecret = usernameSecret;
    this.passwordSecret = passwordSecret;
}
}
```

bootstrap. Properties

```
# Establecer el nombre del archivo de configuración bootstrap
spring.config.name=bootstrap

# Habilitar la carga del archivo bootstrap.properties
spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring.datasource.url=${spring-datasource-url}
spring.datasource.username=${spring-datasource-username}
spring.datasource.password=${spring-datasource-password}

# JPA properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

# Manejar el formato del nombre de las tablas
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded `datasource could be configured.`
```

El problema de fonde es como setear los valores recuperados de Azure Key Vaul para que spring boot pueda leerlo antes que se leea el archivo bootstrap.properties?

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que muestras funciona siempre y cuando no necesites valores que sean precargados antes de que la aplicación inicie, para ese escenario puedes hacer referencia de las credenciales almacenadas en Azure Key Vault directamente en tus archivos `.properties` sin necesidad de inyectarlos con código.

Te recomiendo darle un vistazo a esta documentación que explica cómo hacerlo: [Use Spring Key Vault PropertySource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#use-spring-key-vault-propertysource).

Comment: Gracias Gonzalo funciono.....